# Confusion about "no three queens are in a straight line" property for Eight Queens

Tags: algorithm, n-queens

In the [Wikipedia article for Eight Queen Puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle). The last line of *[solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Solutions)* section is stated as *"Solution 10 has the additional property that no three queens are in a straight line"*.

But isn't that the mission to **not** place any queen in straight line? Why it is special for solution #10, I can see all solutions obey the statement. So what am I overlooking?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, but about understanding what a straight line is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A "straight line" in this context may be diagonal. Look at solution 1: The four leftmost queens are all in a straight line with slope 2/1.

[image]

Each solution besides ten has a similar configuration.

[image]

In contrast, any line you draw on Solution 10 will pass through the center of no more than two queens.

[image]

Comment: So... you just casually keep an image of 8 queens on a chess board with 4 of them on a straight line?!

Comment: Haha, I just took a screenshot of the Wikipedia page :-)

Answer (score 1):

A straight line in the context of grid is equal ratio between the row and column number of the corresponding points on the grid.